# tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy() gives ValueError when calculating loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

so I am trying to load files via tensorflow input pipeline and train my modelon the dataset, but it throws up ValueError, what could be causer of this problem and how can i fix it?

```py
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(DATADIR, image_size=(511, 383), batch_size = None)

with strategy.scope():
    baseModel = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(511, 383, 3))
    baseModel.trainable=False
    # Model With Transfer Learning From Xception
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(baseModel) # Xception
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='leaky_relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # Dropout To Reduce Overfitting
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='leaky_relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(27, activation='softmax'))  # Final Dense Layer - Can Output 27 Classes

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

    # Cmpile The Model
    model.compile(optimizer= optimizer, loss=Custom_MSECE_Loss(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this is error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(dataset, epochs = 32)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

Cell In[7], line 7, in Custom_MSECE_Loss.call(self, y_true, y_pred)
      5 def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
      6     cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
----> 7     cce_loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)
      8     arg_y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
      9     arg_y_true=tf.math.argmax(y_true, axis=1)

ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 27)
```